# .wmv and .wma not playing on Ubuntu 16.04 with Videos and Rhythmbox

Tags: 16.04, gstreamer, wmv, wma

since yesterday I am not longer able to play the audio of .wmv and .wma files with both Videos and Rhythmbox respectively. The errors are

> Required plugin could not be found
>
> Videos requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: > Windows Media Audio 8 decoder

I have the following packages installed:

```
libxvidcore4 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3 gstreamer1.0-libav ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Weirdly even vlc seems to have problems with the audio of such files as it lags behind the video in .wmv.

Thanks for any answers.

UPDATE:

Seems to have to do with this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer1.0/+bug/1661799

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated this is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gst-libav1.0/+bug/1661842) in the package **gstreamer1.0-libav**

1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 of this package fixes this issue. Currently this fix is only in the xenial-proposed repository.

You can either enable proposed repository or download the package manually with the following commands (example for 64bit architecture):

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/306369643/gstreamer1.0-libav_1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i gstreamer1.0-libav_1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
```

For other architectures you can get it from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/gstreamer1.0-libav). Most likely will this be uploaded to mainline very soon.